# Postman: Test not able to reference expected variable

Tags: postman

I'm attempting to write a test that posts a certain API call and gets a response back as expected.

My question revolves around Postman functionality that I have not been able to find through my own attempts of understanding how to do it, google searches, etc.

I have a POST request which includes a `day` key in the body. I gave it a value of 18 for example.

In the test, I am attempting to verify the response which looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": "OK",
        "code": 200
    },
    "errors": [],
    "data": [
        {
          "day": "18"
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, the API call updates the database and assigns the key in the database to be the value given in the API call.

So, day = 18 was passed to the API endpoint and the response reiterated that the day was indeed changed to the value given, which was 18.

**So how can I use the body's "day = 18" to verify in the script?**

I don't want to hard-code 18 in the script as well as the body, which of course would work.

**Is there a way to use the predefined key value in the script, as its own variable?**

Basically I want to be able to do this:

```
pm.test("Day Updated", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.day).to.eql(POST.Body.Key[day]);
});
```

I just made up `POST.Body.Key[day]`, but essentially that is what I am wanting to do.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `jsonData.data[0].day` in the `expect` function to get the right data from the response.

The `eql` value reference is wrong - you could store the value in an environment variable and use the `pm.environment.get('my_value')` to reference it.

In the POST body you could use the same environment variable syntax instead of the hard coded `18` value. Just add `{{my_value}}` to the request body where you have the `18` value

More information on variables can be found here https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables